# Checking to see if a div contains a ul, and then applying a style to the div

Tags: jquery

I have a sceanrio where i want to change the styling of a div IF it contains a UL. Basically, it's an error panel, displaying at the top of the form. If the user has triggered one error, the text is aligned center, if the user has triggered a number of errors, then i want a ul to displayed but want the text aligned to the left.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work - any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
$('.validationSummary').has('ul').css('text-align', 'left');
```

```
<div class="validationSummary">Please correct the errors highlighted below
<ul>
<li>Error 1</li>
<li>Error 2</li>
<li>Error 3</li>
<li>Error 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That _should_ work just fine (as would `$('div.validationSummary:has(ul)')...`). The root of the problem is likely elsewhere. Are you sure that the code runs after document ready?

Comment: Your code does appear to work in the correct context.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wK2Dx/  (I changed the css property to be more visibile)  Is your jquery wrapped in a page load event?  My guess is that you are trying to check the DOM and it hasn't been rendered yet.

Comment: How embarrassing - it wasn't. Added that now and all works fine... this is what happens when you work on a sunday ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think PeeHaa's should be improved to match your requests on the two cases...

```
var $target = $('.validationSummary');
if ($target.find("ul").length > 0) {
    $target..find("ul").css('text-align', 'left');
}
```

and you may want to do something on the else case if the style is not already centered, like

```
... as above ...
} else {
   $target.css('text-align','center');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('.validationSummary ul').length > 0) {
    $('.validationSummary').css('text-align', 'left');
}

<div class="validationSummary">Please correct the errors highlighted below
<ul>
<li>Error 1</li>
<li>Error 2</li>
<li>Error 3</li>
<li>Error 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work like intended, this applies the css to *any* `.validationSummary` if *any* of them have a `<ul>`, you'd want to check each one.

Comment: This is effectively no different from the OP's code. BTW, as a matter of style, you can just check `if ($('.validationSummary ul').length) {...}`